# Linearize an equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

The question is linearize the equation $\frac{du}{dt}=ru\left(1-\frac{u}{C}\right)$ about the solution $u=v^*=C$. So I let $f(u)= ru\left(1-\frac{u}{C}\right)$. I tried linearizing this.
$$f'(u)= r-\frac{2u}{C}$$

$$\begin{align}
L &=& f(u) + f'(u)(u-u_0)\\
&=&f(C) + f'(C)(u-C)\\
&=&0 + (r-2)(u-c)
\end{align}$$

But the answer is $-rCv$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: shouldn't $r$ be multiplying the second term in your derivative as well?

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. But then f′(u)=r−2ur/C. f'(C)= -r so L= -ru+C, which is still not the answer :(

Comment: What is $v$ in the answer?

Comment: Yes, you haven't really told us what $v$, or $v^*$ are?

Comment: To be honest... I have noooo idea. The only time v popped up was in the question where it says that the equation is about the solution u=v*=C

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the answer means.
Actually linearize means, for stationary solution $C$ we know that
$$\frac{dC}{dt}=f(C)=0$$
We suppose there exist a solution $u=C+\epsilon\phi,\ \ \ \phi=u-C,\epsilon<<1$
then
$$\frac{d(C+\epsilon \phi)}{dt}=f(C+\epsilon\phi)=f(C)+f'(C)\epsilon\phi+O(\epsilon^2)$$
then
$$\epsilon\frac{d\phi}{dt}\sim \epsilon f'(C)\phi=\epsilon(-r)\phi$$
From this we get linearized ODE:
$$\frac{d\phi}{dt}+r\phi=0,(\phi=u-C)$$

and the formal way is:

Let $u=C+\epsilon\phi$
,then
$$\epsilon\frac{d\phi}{dt}=r(C+\epsilon\phi)(1-\frac{C+\epsilon\phi}{C})= -r\phi+O(\epsilon^2)$$
So we can get same linearized equation
$$\frac{d\phi}{dt}+r\phi=0$$